# How to rotate an image with Buttons such as left and right using the Rotate Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image">
<button id ="left">left</button>
<button id ="right">Right</button>



        $("#left").click({
            $("#image").rotate({ animateTo:180 })

       });

        $("#right").click({
            $("#image").rotate({animateTo:0})
       });​
```

Iam Not able to rotate the image with buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `function()` part of your click events: http://jsfiddle.net/2G63C/3/

They need to be:

```
$('#left').click(function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to bind a function to the event (inside the 'click' in this case)

```
$("#left").click(function() {
            $("#image").rotate({ animateTo: 180 });

});

$("#right").click(function() {
            $("#image").rotate({ animateTo: 0 })
});​
```